# duplicate attribute error in android studio

Tags: android

I am making an app but getting an error which says R can't resolve. Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

> error: duplicate attribute. Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: duplicate
>   attribute., sources=[/Users/Puja
>   Dudhat/Library/Android/ForecastNEarthquake/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:7],
>   original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

Comment: Can you inspect this file in Android Studio?  Possibly, it will already be highlighting to you where the error is.  If you don't see anything, then try doing a clean followed by a build.

Comment: Kindly close the question if it is solved by adding your answer

Answer (score 4):

I just removed duplicate from xml file which was  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Answer (score 3):

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

**OR**

Any imports are defined more than one in your xml file. Check it once.